# What is a scalable and advanced approach when working with margins in CSS?

Tags: css, sass

Apologies upfront for such a vague question, but for years I am struggling with how to best define margins and padding values in a scalable and productive way.

I constantly feel I am doing it "wrong" (in terms of complicated).

Most of the websites I am working on have a focus on desktop so I define sizes, margins, ... for desktop first using (SASS) variables.

This looks something like that:

```
$margin-base: 20vw; // or px or rem, depending on the type of element
$margin-large: $margin-base * 8;
$margin-medium: $margin-base * 6;
```

The mess always starts when I am going to build the responsive parts. My clients are mostly high end design studios being used to "pixel perfect standards". That comes with having sometimes dozens of breakpoints (not for all elements, but e.g. adjusting text widths is often done for tons of breakpoints).

I've tried applying different variables like
`$main-margin-base` down to `$mobile-margin-base` or attach some kind of "scale values" (e.g. `width: calc(#{$margin-base} * #{$mobile-scale-value});`

But it always ends up either producing too much code / variables or being not adjustable or scalable enough... Is there a good, scalable and major approach to working with variables?

Comment: I can't decide between closing as too broad or opinion based. But my opinion is that a margin of 160vw is too large.

Comment: Hey @MrLister: Serious question, where would go for such a question on the web?

Comment: I don't know, but if you can reword your question to focus on specific problems you run into with the tons of breakpoints to satisfy the clients, it might become on topic here.